# PCHとBIOS間の通信信号からエラーコード等を解析・取得することは可能ですか？

Tags: ハードウェア, bios

趣味でノートパソコンの修理をしています。
修理中によく遭遇する現象に、PLTRST#信号が出力されているにもかかわらず、BIOSが正常に起動しないというものがあります。

このような場合、以下のような限定的な対応しかとれません。

1. BIOSコードを書き換える。
2. メモリ関連の問題を調査する。
3. CPUの故障としてあきらめる。

大抵の原因不明のものはCPUの故障と判断し修理不可とするしかないのが実情です。

ただ、もっと詳細な原因を突き止めたいと思っています。

そこで、ロジックアナライザやオシロスコープのデコード機能を使い、PCHとBIOS間のSPI通信を解析することで何かしら情報を得ることは可能でしょうか？
（PCHとBIOS間のSPI通信でエラーコードなどのやり取りがあるのでしょうか？）

あるいは、そもそも、これは不可能なことなのでしょうか？